# PHP MySQL JQuery Back-End for Data Driven Menu

Tags: jquery, reorderlist

I am looking for tutorials, articles etc. on how to create a JQuery reorder list for administration of a data driven menu. Instead of typing in parent ids for positioning, I want to be able to drag menu items into position or use up/down arrows or something similar that creates a more intuitive and visual way to manipulate menu items.

Can anyone suggest anything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created an example to show the basic principal behind such a menu. It's very bare bones but maybe it will get you started. http://jsfiddle.net/Zevan/UxLqV/2/

The key is basically:

1. draw a few divs based on outside information
2. make the divs vertically draggable
3. onmouseup sort all the divs on their Y position and correct any messed up spacing resulting from the drag

Comment: Glad it helps. Let me know if you have any questions about it.